# how can I simply pull the latest 10 tweets from the same user in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

I am trying to use twitter api to pull 10 latest tweets of a user in javascript.  There are many resources out there that seem too complicated.  I have made twitter developer account with api key + secret.  Is there a simple method to return JSON format of tweet?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});

var params = {screen_name: 'nodejs' , count: 5};
client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(tweets);
  }
});
```